# Problem generating rig

Tags: rigging

I created a human armature, created the rig using the button "generate rig", then parented the model to the rig using automatic weights. I can move the hands, the feet and so on but the arms and legs rotation seems not be bound to the model. Can anyone help me solving this problem? Thanks. Giulio

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Rigify you can control arms and legs in two ways: FK and IK. When using one method the other is temporarily disabled, so it seems to have no effect.

You can decide which to use with the top slider in my example image, where one arm is set to IK and the other to FK: if the slider is set to 0.0 you are using IK, if set to 1.0 FK (Inverse Kinematics - Forward Kinematics).

[image]

Comment: Thnaks a lot !! I have learned something more about blender...